# Calculate Earth Movers Distance on samples

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I understand how to calculate the Earth Movers Distance [Earth Movers Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) of discrete distributions. However, how would I calculate it if I only have sets of samples $\in \mathbb{R}^N$ from two different distributions? (I assume that one uses every sample as its own cluster and move it to a partner sample of the other distribution?).

If that is correct, how is it with different amount of samples in the two sets from the two distributions?

Comment: You'd have to weight each sample in the two sets so that the total weight of all samples in each set is the same. At least that's one approach.